# Good books about differentiation in normed spaces?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, normed-spaces

Typical functional analysis books don't seem to cover this subject at all, so I'm looking for some good books that deal with differentiation in normed spaces(Gateaux/Frechet derivatives etc.). Preferably moving also into other calculus-like topics in infinite dimensional spaces, like integration on Banach spaces, perhaps Banach manifolds. Any recommendations?

Comment: Cartan's Differential Calculus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my suggestions:

- Differentiation: Differential calculus by Cartan: http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Differential_calculus.html?id=PIg_AQAAIAAJ; Covers derivatives (also Taylor approximation), ODEs in Banach spaces
- Integration: Vector measures by Diestel/Uhl: http://books.google.de/books/about/Vector_Measures.html?id=NCm4E2By8DQC&redir_esc=y; Covers vector-valued functions and their integration (Bochner integral and other concepts)

Comment: I wish Dover would republish Cartan's Differential Calculus together with his differential forms lectures in a single text,as the lectures were originally intended to be read and digested. It would make his forms lectures far more accessible at a great price.

Answer (score 2):

There's a very nice elementary chapter in Kenneth Hoffman's *Analysis in Euclidean Space*,which I heartily recommend as an offbeat analysis text at the baby Rudin level, where **everything** is done on normed spaces.

Answer (score 0):

One that I found helpful **Foundations of Modern Analysis** by **J Dieudonne**.
[https://www.amazon.com/Foundations-Modern-Analysis-J-Dieudonne/dp/1406727911](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1406727911)